# How to use EAV to designing Object based on Class, Attribute and value?

Tags: entity-attribute-value

I want to design a system that a user can define class, object, attribute and value flexibly and objects can bound to class(es) then get attributes of class and then have values for each attribute.

I want to set multiple value for some attribute for example if an object has 2 phone number for 2 place (phone and number are attributes of Location Class) I want to know that which phone is for which place for 1 object? What is the best designing?

My design is like bellow:

- Class: `Id`, `Name`
- Object: `Id`, `Name`
- ClassObject: `Id`, `ClassId`, `ObjectId`
- Attribute: `Id`, `Name`, `ClassId`
- Value: `Id`, `ClassObjectId`, `AttributeId`, `Value`

Comment: **Please help me as soon as possible !!!**

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your design question:
In order to associate the phone and place you have to use an additional class "place" and give the attribute "phone" to class "place". An instance of class "location" may have 2 instances of class "place".

This requires that you have another two tables:

- "link": Id, SourceId, TargetId,RelationId
- "relation": Id, SourceClassId, TargetClassId, Name

Btw. Your metamodel is interesting: it is very flexible by allowing an object to belong to multiple classes.
Hence you can express:
Object "Arnold Schwarzenegger" belongs to classes: BodyBuilder, Immigrnt, Actor, Book Author, Businessman, Politician.

On the other hand you have no inheritance / subtype relationship between classes.
It seems that you have no explicit value type declaration in your attribute definition.